# Multiplicar un campo con texto con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo poco conocimiento con javascript pero en vista del codigo creo poder entenderlo para realizar algo que necesito,le realizo mantenimiento a un proyecto y me pidieron lo siguiente, en esta imagen yo coloco en el campo Producto cualquier dato en este caso "COCA" y me busca los resultado que consiga en tiempo real.

[image]

Busco otros productos y al seleccionarlo queda deshabilitado para que no sobrescriban sobre el como se ve en esta imagen
[image]

Lo que Necesito es multiplicar el valor de precio por el campo **Cantidad por Entregar**.

agregue un input que dice Calcular total, para que alli se vea reflejado el total de lo que ha seleccionado.

Mi pregunta es como hacerlo o obtener el valor de precio? que me recomiendan ustedes para hacerlo

ANEXO Código JavaScript Donde Busca el Producto por medio de un WebService

```
function doneTypingSearch() {
$('.producto').autocomplete({        
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
           url: "https://api.TESTl.com.ve/Rest/PublicService.svc/FindProducts",
            type: "POST", contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            crossOrigin: true,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Search: request.term,
                 ApiKey: "VS2015-VS2015",
                Count: 100,
                StartIndex: 0,
                StoreId: "A001"
            }),
            success: function( data ) {
       
                var res = data;
                var availableTags = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.Products.length; i++) {
                    var principio = data.Products[i].ActiveIngredient != "" ? " - " + data.Products[i].ActiveIngredient : "";
                    var precio = data.Products[i].LastFullPrice != 0 ? " Precio: "+ (data.Products[i].LastFullPrice).toFixed(2) : "";
                    var opt = data.Products[i].Description + principio + precio;
                    availableTags.push({ label: opt, id: data.Products[i].Id, indice: i });
                }
                 response( availableTags );
            },
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        desbloquearGuardar();
        var sapCode = ui.item.id;
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        $($(this).nextAll("input[type=hidden]")).val(sapCode || "");
    },
    open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }
}, function () {
        }, 300);
}
```

ANEXO Código JavaScript Donde posiciona el producto

```
function NuevaPosicion() {
var indice = parseInt($("input#indice").val());
var productoAnterior = $('input[data-id=' + indice + '].producto').val() != null ? $('input[data-id=' + indice + '].producto').val().trim() : "";
var cantidadAnterior = $('input[data-id=' + indice + '].cantidad').val() != null ? $('input[data-id=' + indice + '].cantidad').val().trim() : "0";

if (($('input[data-id=' + indice + '].cantidad').val() == null && $('input[data-id=' + indice + '].producto').val() == null) || (productoAnterior != "" && !isNaN(parseInt(cantidadAnterior)) && parseInt(cantidadAnterior) > 0)) {
    indice = indice + 1;
    $("input#indice").val(indice);
    $("#tblPosicionesNueva").append('<tr>'+

     //CAMPO PRODUCTO
     '<td><input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="producto" placeholder="Nombre y Presentación" data-id="' + indice + '" required style="width: 100%" list="searchresults' + indice + '" /><datalist id="searchresults' + indice + '"></datalist><input type="hidden" data-id="' + indice + '" class="sap"></td> ' +
    
    //CAMPO CANTIDAD POR ENTREGAR
     '<td class="cssCenterTd"><input type="number" min="1" max="10" value="1" step="1"class="cantidad justNumbers" data-id="' + indice + '" required style="width: 50px" /><input type="hidden" class="idPosicionOrden" data-id="' + indice + '" value="-1"/></td> ' +
    //CAMPO ELIMINAR
     '<td class="cssCenterTd"><a id="eliminar' + indice + '" class="fa-stack fa-lg" href="javascript:EliminarPosicion(' + indice + ')" title="Eliminar"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-fondo"></i><i class="fa fa-trash fa-stack-1x fa-frente"></i></a></td></tr>');

    $('input[data-id=' + indice + '].producto').focus();
    $("#tblPosicionesNueva tbody tr input[type=number]").on('blur', function () {
        NuevaPosicion();
    });
    $('input.justNumbers').keydown(function (evt) {
        return validaTecla(evt);
    });
}
$('input[required]').on('blur change keypress focus', function () {
    desbloquearGuardar();
});
var desbloquear = true;
$('input[required]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim() == "") {
        desbloquear = false;
    }
});
if ($("#tblPosicionesNueva tbody tr").length >= 1 && desbloquear)
    $('#btnGuardar').prop("disabled", false);
else
    $('#btnGuardar').prop("disabled", true);
doneTypingSearch();
}
```

Anexo codigo cshtml

```
@using TPConvenios.App_Data;
@using TPConvenios.Models;
@model Orden
@{
    Layout = null;

    AjaxOptions ajaxOpciones = new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "cuerpoPopUpGenerico",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
        OnFailure = "OnFailure"
    };
    List<Item> items = ViewBag.listaItems;
    List<AtributoAdicional> atributosAdicionales = ViewBag.ListaAtributosAdicionales;
    string codConvenio = ViewBag.codConvenio;
    bool tieneEntregas = items.Any(i => i.tieneEntregas);
    bool tieneRepetidos = items.Any(i => i.repetido);
    int j = 0;
}
<input type="hidden" id="tieneRepetidos" value="@tieneRepetidos.ToString().ToLower()" />
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete
    {
        max-height: 100px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    /* IE 6 doesn't support max-height
   * we use height instead, but this forces the menu to always be this tall
   */
    * html .ui-autocomplete
    {
        height: 100px;
    }

    .box
    {
        width: 250px;
        float: left;
        height: 25px;
    }
</style>
<div id="botonesContenedorCarga" style="float: right; display: none;">
    <input type="button" align="center" class="botonNuevo" onclick="NuevaPosicion();"
        value="Agregar Producto" />
</div>
@if (Model.idOrden == 0 || ViewBag.duplicado)
{
    <h1>Nueva Orden</h1>
}
else
{
    <h1>Orden N° @Model.idOrden <span style="color: red">@(Model.FechaHasta.Date < DateTime.Now.Date ? "Vencida" : (!Model.Activa ? "Inactiva" : string.Empty))
        @(Model.Eliminada ? " - Eliminada" : string.Empty)</span></h1>
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NuevaOrden", "Ordenes", null, ajaxOpciones, new { id = "NuevaOrden", onsubmit = "GuardarOrden();" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
    <input type="hidden" name="codigoConvenio" id="codigoConvenio" value="@ViewBag.codConvenio" />
    <input type="hidden" name="confirmadoRepeticion" id="confirmadoRepeticion" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="idOrden" id="idOrden" value="@(ViewBag.duplicado ? 0 : Model.idOrden)" />

 </div>

<br />

<div align="right">
    <input type="button" align="right" class="botonNuevo" value="Calcular Total" />

    <input type="text" align="right" />
</div>
 
    <div id="div_tblPosiciones">
        <table id="tblPosicionesNueva">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Producto
                    </th>
                   
                    <th align="center">Cantidad por<br />
                        Entregar
                    </th>
                    
                    <th>
                        Eliminar
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (null != items)
                {
                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        j++;
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="producto" autocomplete="off" id="inputBusqueda" style="width: 100%;@(item.repetido ? "border-color:transparent transparent #FCBB1D;" : string.Empty)" placeholder="Nombre y Presentación" data-id="@j"
                                required value="@item.nombre"/>
                            <input type="hidden" class="sap" data-id="@j" value="@item.sap"/>
                        </td>
                        <td><!--// ESTE <TD> LO INCLUI PARA INCORPORAR EL PRECIO -->
                            <input type="text" class="producto" autocomplete="off" id="IP" style="width: 100%" required value="@item.precio" />
                            <input type="hidden" class="sap" data-id="@j" value="@item.sap" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="cssCenterTd">
                            <input type="number" min="0" value="@item.cantidad" step="1" class="cantidad justNumbers" data-id="@j"
                                required style="width: 50px" />
                            <input type="hidden" class="posicion" data-id="@j" value="@item.posicion"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cssCenterTd">
                            <a id="eliminar@(j)" class="fa-stack fa-lg @(item.tieneEntregas ? "fa-disabled" : string.Empty)" href="javascript:EliminarPosicion('@j')"
                                title="Eliminar"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-fondo"></i><i class="fa fa-trash fa-stack-1x fa-frente"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="indice" name="indice" value="@j" />
    <input type="hidden" id="listaProductos" name="listaProductos" />
    <input type="hidden" id="codConvenio" name="codConvenio" value="@(ViewBag.codConvenio)" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>
        <input type="button" class="botonNuevo botonSuccess" onclick="CancelarNuevaOrden()"
            style="float: right; margin-top: 0; position: relative; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;"
            value="Cancelar" />
        <input type="submit" id="btnGuardar" class="botonNuevo botonSuccess" style="float: right; margin-top: 0; position: relative;"
            value="Guardar" disabled />
    </p>
}
<script src='@Url.Content("~/" + String.Format("Scripts/jsOrden/jsNuevaOrden.js?v={0}", File.GetLastWriteTime(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/Scripts/jsOrden/jsNuevaOrden.js").ToString("yyyyMMddHHss")))' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

De que manera puedo lograr esto acepto todas sus sugerencias para yo analizar e implementarla en el código para lograr lo que propuesto

Agradezco la ayuda que puedan brindarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre que quieras extraer un número de una cadena podes usar [Expresiones Regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de cómo:

```js
const cantidadPorEntregar = document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
const producto = document.getElementById('producto').value;

/* 
  esto es una expresión regular (\d+) significa todos los números
*/
const regex = /precio: (\d+)/i;

/*
  esta función se usa para buscar expresiones regulares en una cadena de texto y 
  devuelve un array con las coincidencias 
*/
const match = producto.match(regex);
const precio = parseInt(match[1]);

const total = precio * cantidadPorEntregar;
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = `Total: ${total}`;
```

```html
<input id="producto" type="text" value="Coca-Cola Precio: 1234">
<input id="cantidad" type="text" value="2">
<p id="total"></p>
```

Comment: gracias por responder y pues te diré que con eso si obtengo el valor del precio, ahora debo trabajar en incluir eso y sacar el total en todo eso código que tengo, lo veo complicado