# Sumar el Total de varias filas de multiplicación con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, visual-studio

Tengo un código sencillo, con el que planteo realizar una operación y al funcionar colocárselo a un cogido mas [grande](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/434712/multiplicar-un-campo-con-texto-con-javascript)  necesito sumar el total de mi multiplicación y colocarlo en un input en tiempo real.

Como Funciona,en el primer campo en vez de colocar un numero cualquiera coloco **Precio: 7**, en el otro campo es tipo number por lo cual puedo controlar el numero por el que quiero que se multiplique y lo muestra en el otro campo, al pulsar **Agregar Producto** crea otra linea con la que puedo seguir multiplicando como se ve en la imagen

[image]

Lo que necesito es sumar el total de esas multiplicación y mostrarla en el campo que dice total. use un for pero solo me muestra el total de cualquiera de las lineas que toco, cuan debe sumarse todas las lineas

Anexo Codigo para que lo ejecuten y puedan ver como funciona.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es_ES">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var nextinput = 0;
        function AgregarCampos(){
            nextinput++;
            campo = '<li id="idLi'+nextinput+'">' +
            '<input type="text" size="15" id="txt' + nextinput + '" step="any" oninput="multiplicar(\'txt' + nextinput + '\',\'nmb' + nextinput + '\',\'acumu' + nextinput + '\');" />' +
            '<input type="number" size="15" id="nmb' + nextinput + '" step="any" oninput="multiplicar(\'txt' + nextinput + '\',\'nmb' + nextinput + '\',\'acumu' + nextinput + '\');" />' +
            '<input type="text" size="15" id="acumu' + nextinput + '" step="any"/></li>';

            $("#campos").append(campo);
        }
        function multiplicar(txt, nmb, acumu) {

            var m1 = document.getElementById(txt).value; 
            var m2 = document.getElementById(nmb).value;
            var P = /precio: (\d+)/i;
            var match = m1.match(P);
            var Price = parseInt(match[1]);

            r = Price * m2;
            document.getElementById(acumu).value = r;

            let total = 0, numeros = acumu;
            for(let i of numeros) total += i;
            document.getElementById('T').value = r;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" name="form" method="post">
         <div align="left">
    <a href="#" onclick="AgregarCampos();">Agregar Producto</a>
    <ul id="campos"></ul>
        <tr>
                <td>
                    Total
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="T" value="0" disabled>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Gracias por su ayuda y sugerencia que puedan brindarme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario asignar IDs dinámicos a los campos, sería más fácil si les asignas nombre y, si esperas enviarlo poder usarlos después, conviene agregar corchetes `[]` para que sean tratados como arreglos al procesar el formulario. Solo el campo de total necesita ID para poder acceder fácilmente y asignar el valor.

De esta forma, envías el evento a la función y, desde ahí, puedes obtener los 3 elementos necesarios para multiplicar y, posteriormente, sumar.

- En los selectores de jQuery el `^` es para especificar que el nombre del campo comienza con la cadena especificada.
- Luego, una expresión regular más adecuada para "limpiar" el precio es `/\D/g`, que va a tomar todos los caracteres no numéricos para eliminarlos con `.replace()`.
- Para asegurar que obtienes un número, si algo falla con `parseInt()`, se agrega `|| 0` al final de la sentencia. Por ejemplo, un campo vacío podría devolver `NaN`
- Realizas la multiplicación y la asignas al campo correspondiente
- Al final, recorres todos los campos `acumu` para sumarlos y mostrar el total

```js
var nextinput = 0;
function AgregarCampos(){
    nextinput++;
    campo = `<li id="idLi${nextinput}">
            <input type="text" size="15" name="txt[]" step="any" oninput="multiplicar(event);" value="Precio: ">
            <input type="number" size="15" name="nmb[]" step="any" oninput="multiplicar(event);">
            <input type="text" size="15" name="acumu[]" step="any" disabled>
        </li>`;

    $("#campos").append(campo);
}
function multiplicar(e) {
    // Obtener LI padre desde el evento
    let li = $(e.target).closest('li');
    // Obtener texto de precio, separando por 'Precio:'
    let textos = $(li).find('[name^="txt"]').val().split('Precio:');
    // Obtener precio desde el último elemento de textos
    let precio = parseInt(textos[textos.length - 1]) || 0;
    // Obtener cantidad
    let cantidad = parseInt($(li).find('[name^="nmb"]').val()) || 0;
    // Multiplicar y asignar
    $(li).find('[name^="acumu"]').val(precio * cantidad);
    
    // Inicializar total
    let total = 0;
    // Recorrer todos los acumulados para sumar
    $('[name^="acumu"]').each((index, item) => {
        // Incrementar total
        total += parseInt($(item).val());
    });
    $('#total').val(total);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form id="form" name="form" method="post">
         <div align="left">
    <a href="#" onclick="AgregarCampos();">Agregar Producto</a>
    <ul id="campos"></ul>
        <tr>
                <td>
                    Total
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="total" value="0" disabled>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**Importante:** Ya tienes cargada la libería jQuery, lo mejor es usar sus métodos para acceder a elementos y realizar operaciones. No tiene sentido combinar con Javascript puro.

Comment: No sabia usar los métodos de JQuery por eso solo usaba Javascript hasta donde lo conozco, Pero Tu código por obvia razones esta mas limpio que el mio y optimizado, Gracias por la explicación y la respuesta esta perfecta gracias por tus conocimientos, debo aprender mas

Comment: @TheRiddler, de hecho, todo esto se puede hacer casi de la misma forma sin jQuery, pero lo apliqué porque vi que lo estás cargando desde el inicio, si es solo para agregar los elementos, entonces no es necesaria la librería.

Comment: exacto ese script de la librería es para cargar los elementos y poder añadir cada linea al darle clic, ademas como dije al inicio esto es algo que hice de manera rápida para luego intentar incluirla en un proyecto grande como lo comente arriba en mi pregunta donde deje el enlace

Comment: @TheRiddler, lo siento, no había visto ese enlace.

Comment: por curiosidad que tan complejo ves hacer lo que pregunte allí? estoy intentando realizarlo, pero estoy iniciando MVC y posiblemente me de mis golpes

Comment: @TheRiddler, es más o menos lo mismo que aquí, solo necesitas identificar los elementos para realizar las operaciones.

Comment: Correcto, Comenzare con Eso, te doy las gracias nuevamente amigo

Comment: una consulta en el campo donde coloco Precio: intento obtener el valor después de esa palabra, en tu código lo que hace es simplemente tomar los numero que consiga y multiplicarlo, es decir si yo coloco jugo 1litro Precio: 5. El va a multiplicar 15 cuando debería multiplicar por 5. No se si puedas ayudarme allí, en esa corrección

Comment: Listo, prueba ahora.

Comment: Gracias Amigo :) Funciona bien

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaze esto

```
            let total = 0, numeros = acumu;
            for(let i of numeros) total += i;
            document.getElementById('T').value = r;
```

por esto

```
var total = 0;
            $(".monto").each(function () {
                if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
                    total += 0;
                } else {
                    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
                }
            });
            document.getElementById('T').value = total;
        }
```

En esta linea le agregue la class monto

```
'<input type="text" size="15" id="acumu' + nextinput + '" step="any" class="monto" /></li>';
```

Y Funciono bien